# Reading txt file in which a new row starts every n line, delimited by special character

Tags: r, data.table, bioinformatics, fasta

I am reading a file that contains data about amino acid sequences for approx. 600000 proteins.
[for whomever this might be of interest, here the source](https://www.rcsb.org/downloads/fasta)

I am using `data.table::fread` due to the file size and for convenience.
The "problem" is that the file contains a new entry only every 2nd line, introduced with a ">". It's not a biggie, because I can just do some minor wrangling and I have it as I want. (see desired output, or even "ideal output").

I wondered if there is a direct way to read in a file that has this kind of structure. Any other package also welcome of course, but it should handle that type of size well.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# "text = ..." contains a shortened version of the first two entries of the downloaded txt file
prot <- data.table::fread(text = 
">101m_A mol:protein length:154  MYOGLOBIN
QGAMNKALEL
>102l_A mol:protein length:165  T4 LYSOZYME
RAKRVITTFR", 
header = FALSE
)

prot <- as.data.frame(prot)

# expected output
exp_out <- bind_cols(prot = prot[c(T, F), ], aminoseq = prot[c(F, T), ] )
exp_out
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   prot                                        aminoseq  
#>   <chr>                                       <chr>     
#> 1 >101m_A mol:protein length:154  MYOGLOBIN   QGAMNKALEL
#> 2 >102l_A mol:protein length:165  T4 LYSOZYME RAKRVITTFR

# ideal output
exp_out %>%
  separate(prot, c("mol", "length"), sep = ":protein length:") %>%
  separate(length, c("length", "name"), sep = "\\s{2}+")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   mol         length name        aminoseq  
#>   <chr>       <chr>  <chr>       <chr>     
#> 1 >101m_A mol 154    MYOGLOBIN   QGAMNKALEL
#> 2 >102l_A mol 165    T4 LYSOZYME RAKRVITTFR
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: It seems you are reading FASTA files. Take a look at `readDNAStringSet` https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html

Comment: @MrGumble It actually allows "direct" reading, but it then stores it as an S4 object and in this particular case that's not quite what I need. Thanks many times though for pointing to this interesting package!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read odd and even rows separately, [using sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53533/16560), then *fread* with column bind, this will get you to "expected output", it is pretty fast, too, around 2 seconds with unzipped input:

```
# get the data
# wget ftp://ftp.wwpdb.org/pub/pdb/derived_data/pdb_seqres.txt.gz
library(data.table)

# unzip on the fly
started.at = proc.time()
d <- cbind(
  fread(cmd = "zcat pdb_seqres.txt.gz | sed -n 'p;n'", sep = "|"),
  fread(cmd = "zcat pdb_seqres.txt.gz | sed -n 'n;p'"))
cat("Finished in", timetaken(started.at), "\n")
# Finished in 4.585s elapsed (1.788s cpu)

# read unzipped input
started.at = proc.time()
d <- cbind(
  fread(cmd = "sed -n 'p;n' pdb_seqres.txt", sep = "|"),
  fread(cmd = "sed -n 'n;p' pdb_seqres.txt"))
cat("Finished in", timetaken(started.at), "\n")
# Finished in 1.796s elapsed (1.111s cpu)
```

In theory below should work, i.e. we are column binding using bash *paste* before *freading*, but it keeps giving me errors about tempfile permissions, might work on your set up.

```
fread(cmd = "paste -d'|' <(sed -n 'p;n' pdb_seqres.txt) <(sed -n 'n;p' pdb_seqres.txt)",
      sep = "|")
```